# ValueError: Cannot convert ['RID39466', 'RID39056', 'RID3874'] to Excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is my dictionary: `{'MASS': ['RID39466', 'RID39056', 'RID3874'], 'RIGHT LOWER LOBE': ['RID1315'], 'RIGHT': ['RID5825'], 'LOWER': ['RID46058'], 'LOBE': ['RID5967'], 'LUNG': ['RID1301']}`

How do I write this dictionary into an Excel spreadsheet so that there are only two columns? It should look like this:

```
|Text             | RID                       | 
|——————————————————————————————————————————————
|MASS             |RID39466, RID39056, RID3874|
|RIGHT LOWER LOBE |RID 1315                   |
|RIGHT            |RID5825                    |
 .
 .
 .
```

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

annDict = {'MASS': ['RID39466', 'RID39056', 'RID3874'], 'RIGHT LOWER LOBE': ['RID1315'], 'RIGHT': ['RID5825'], 'LOWER': ['RID46058'], 'LOBE': ['RID5967'], 'LUNG': ['RID1301']}

row = 1
    for key,values in annDict.items():
        # Put the key in the first column for each key in the dictionary
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=key)
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=values)
        row += 1

    workbook.save(filename="my_workbook.xlsx")
```

When I do this, I get a ValueError saying that I can't put all the items in the list into the cell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ga.py", line 57, in <module>
    print_annotations(annotations)
  File "ga.py", line 49, in print_annotations
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=values)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 240, in cell
    cell.value = value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 216, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert ['RID39466', 'RID39056', 'RID3874'] to Excel
```

Comment: Replace with `value=', '.join(values)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that a `list`-object is not a valid value for a `cell`-object. To fix this you would have to pass a valid value e.g. a `string`, `float` etc. The result you want in the second column is a comma-separated list. In order to convert the values in the dictionary to a string of the correct format, you could use the `join`-method as mentioned in the comments.

```py
'sep'.join(lst)
```

takes all the values in `lst` and join them in a string separated by `sep`. Thus

```py
', '.join(values)
```

evaluates to a string that represents a comma-separated list. You can pass this string as a valid `value` of a `cell`-object.